# Read values from Error ErrorType in dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-component, mulesoft

Need small help to retrieve values which are in error.errorType as per attached screenshot.

I need values of asString, identifier and namespace from error.errorType.

And need dataweave expression code to write in transform message in Mulesoft.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvmot.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to these with the .(dot) notation and that should work for you?

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    errorAsString: error.errorType.asString,
    errorIdentifier: error.errorType.identifier,
    errorNamespace: error.errorType.namespace
}
```

Grabbed a screenshot for you from a sample app that i created to demonstrate this.

[image]